# Playing a simple Audio file in iOS

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

A very common question but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in playing a simple audio file in iOS 10 and 9. I have the following code:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

    NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www/sounds/ringbacktone" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    [self playTone:soundFilePath Loop:YES];

-(void) playTone:(NSString *) soundFilePath Loop:(BOOL) loop{


    NSLog(@"Sound File Path: %@",soundFilePath);


    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:soundFilePath]){

        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

        NSError *error = nil;
        AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];

        if (error){
            NSLog(@"Error creating the audio player: %@",error);
        }else{
            if (loop == YES)
                player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

            [player setVolume:1.0];
            [player play];
        }

    }else{
        NSLog(@"No sound will be played. The file doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Sound File Path: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8CCA88C-B6AB-4C36-9426-EFBB94E1D509/myapp.app/www/sounds/myfile.mp3
```

The file exists so the sound should play. I've tried wav,m4a and mp3 files without success.

I'm using the function before calling pjsip library. Not sure if it plays a role.

Any thoughts? Is there any other way to debug it further?

Comment: Are you enabled audio session? What category you use?

Comment: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord

Answer (score 0):

**check this solution it may work :**

1.create property for ur audio player:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

2.write delegate methods for player:  **AVAudioPlayerDelegate**

3.implement this in ur action :

```
yourSoundArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sound1",@"sound2",@"sound3",@"sound4",@"sound5",@"sound6", nil];//dont include formate type


   NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [yourSoundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"mp3"];
                    NSLog(@"%@",audioPath);

                    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];

                    NSError *audioError = [[NSError alloc] init];
                    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&audioError];
                    audioPlayer.delegate=self;

                 if (!audioError) {
                        NSLog(@"playing!");
                        audioPlayer play];
                  }
                    else {
                          NSLog(@"Error!");
                    }
```

4. **check the audio player-delegate action**

   ```
     -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player    successfully:(BOOL)flag
                   { NSLog(@"%d",playing the audio);
                    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a combination of these:
in .h file I had to inherit from AVAudioPlayerDelegate, i.e.

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface scAudioManager : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
```

And then in .m file:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www/sounds/ringbacktone" ofType:@"mp3"]];
[self playTone:soundFilePath Loop:YES];

-(void) playTone:(NSString *) soundFilePath Loop:(BOOL) loop{

    NSLog(@"Sound File Path: %@",soundFilePath);


    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:soundFilePath]){

        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

        NSError *error = nil;
        _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];

        if (error){
            NSLog(@"Error creating the audio player: %@",error);
        }else{
            if (loop == YES)
                _player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

             _player.volume=[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
            _player.delegate = self;
            [_player prepareToPlay]
            [_player play];
        }

    }else{
        NSLog(@"No sound will be played. The file doesn't exist.");
    }

}
```